# Error with Twine: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I am trying to upload a package to PyPi; however, when I use the recommended platform `twine` to connect to PyPi, I get this error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upload.pypi.org', port=443): 
Maxretries exceeded with url: /legacy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(8, '_ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol'),))
```

Here is the twine command that I ran:

```
twine register dist/wikiparser-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also got this error while uploading a package to `PyPi`, but my workaround was to upload the package manually.

So back to work,

1. Create your account here https://pypi.python.org/pypi
2. Package your code upto the 3rd point in this [link](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
3. You will get a tarball after step 2, upload that tarball to the pypi account manually

Comment: There should be a link there to upload the zip file